# How can I determine the bounds for this inequality?

Tags: inequality

I have the following inequality:

$$ -40 < \bigg(\frac{a}{2^{52}}\bigg) (2^{b}) < 40 ,\ \text{with}\ a \in [-2^{52}, 2^{52}]\ \text{and}\ b \in [-1024, 1024].$$

How can I "thin" the range of $a$ and $b$ so as to exclude all solutions that are not within $[-40, 40]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $a=0$ is a solution for all $b$.
2. if $a,b$ is a solution then so is $-a,b$.

Therefore lets write $a=\pm 2^c$ where $c\leq 52$. Then the original inequality becomes:

$$-40 < \pm \frac{2^c}{2^{52}} (2^b) < 40$$

equivalent to

$$ \frac{2^c}{2^{52}} (2^b) < 40$$

can be simplified to

$$ 2^{b+c-52}<40$$

and therefore

$$ b+c < \log_240+52$$